# Button.setText is not working

Tags: android, text, android-button, android-selector

I am trying to create a `Button` programmatically using a `drawable selector`.

After I did the configuration, I tried to set the text of the `Button` using `setText()` method but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    Button b = new Button(this);
    int pxw = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.level_button_width);
    int pxh = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.level_button_height);
    LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(pxw,pxh);
    lp.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8);
    b.setLayoutParams(lp);
    b.setShadowLayer(8, 0, 0, 0xA8A8A8);
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.level_button));
    } else {
        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.level_button));
    }

    b.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);
    b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 36);
    b.setText("heey");

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startlevel(Integer.parseInt((String) ((Button)v).getText()));                   
    }
});
mLinearLevel.addView(b);
```

And here is my drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/level_button_disabled" />

<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/level_button_pressed"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/level_button_normal"/>      
</selector>
```

The result is a custom button with no text.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Check my answer below.

Comment: Are you try to change the font color  ?

Comment: I tried and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is `Color.parseColor()` method. I changed it as in mohammed's comment and it worked.

```
b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```